# Detecting circles with OpenCV in a Win10 C++ Universal App

Tags: c++, opencv

I have some issues detecting circles in a Win10 Universal App (C++).
I Need to detect the blue circles in the following Image:

[image]

For that reason I am using OpenCV with the following code:

```
    Mat img_image = imread("template_rund.png");
    Mat img_hsv;
    Mat img_result;
    Mat img_blue;
    Mat img_canny;

    cvtColor(img_image, img_image, CV_BGR2BGRA);
    cv::cvtColor(img_image, img_hsv, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    cv::inRange(img_hsv, cv::Scalar(100, 50, 0), cv::Scalar(140, 255, 255), img_blue);
    cv::Canny(img_blue, img_canny, 300, 350);
    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;
    GaussianBlur(img_canny, img_canny, cv::Size(9, 9), 2, 2);
    cv::HoughCircles(img_canny, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 5, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000);

    for (size_t current_circle = 0; current_circle < circles.size(); ++current_circle) {
        ...
    }
```

The algorithm is working fine until the HoughCircles-call.
Inside the circles-vector should be stored all found circles.
But the size of the vector is always about 1537228453755672812

At that Point i thought it would be a good idea to Change the Parameters of the HoughCircles-Call. B ut if I Change the min/max-radius to lets say 10/100, the algorithm still find around 1517229... Circles.

What could be the problem?

Further Info:

I compiled the OCV-Libraries for Windows by myself:
https://msopentech.com/blog/2015/05/15/uap-in-action-running-opencv-on-raspberry-pi-ii/#

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35847950/5008845)

Comment: Perfect!   Thats it! Thx